wso2 : avoiding special character error in scope naming
It is a good recommendation to name scopes as such : urn:examplecompany:product_price:update, this is the naming convention we use at our company. but WSO2 publisher doesn't allow special characters including ":" character in scopes creation. Is there a way to overcome this ?
scopes field validation error

What's the APIM version you are using?

APIM 2.6, IS 5.7
